# „Alles aussteigen bitte“: Warum „alles“?

Tags: phrase, pronoun, indefinite-pronoun

> Endstation, **alles** aussteigen bitte.
> Endstation, **alle** aussteigen bitte.

Beides klingt vertraut, aber wieso *alles*?

Ich interpretiere *alle* hier als *alle Leute*, aber ich finde kein akzeptables Bezugswort für *alles*.

Im [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/alles) wird als Synonym für *alles* auch *alle Leute* genannt, es wird aber nicht erklärt.

Comment: Besonders idomatisch: "Alles Walzer!" beim Wiener Opernball hat obendrein kein Verb

Answer (score 10):

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/alles) bietet als Synonyme für *alles* an:

> die Gesamtheit · was auch immer

Das scheint auch bei *Alles auf die Plätze* oder *Alles, was Odem hat, lobe den Herrn* zu passen. Ein weiterer Vorteil ist, dass *Alles* auch Hunde, Katzen, oder Gegenstände umfassen kann (auch wenn letztere sich in Deinem Beispiel mit dem Aussteigen schwer tun).

Kurz: Man muss sich nicht einmal auf das Substantiv festlegen, das dann weggelassen wird.

Answer (score 4):

> Alle aussteigen, bitte!

Hier steht *alle* nicht (notwendigerweise) als Attribut zu einem ausgelassenen Bezugswort (Leute).
Es kann auch als Nominativ Plural (für alle Genus) für sich stehen ([Flektion von *all*](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Pronomen/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-all3.html#id=1.5.1.7.1)).

> Alles aussteigen!

Parallel dazu kann *alles* Nominativ Singular (nur Neutrum) sein und genau dasselbe bedeuten.